# SQL Query, within php

Tags: php, sql

I currently have a query

> $query = "SELECT * FROM routes ORDER
>   BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8;";

And that works all wonderfully.

I have table columns

```
id      int(10)            
name    varchar(45)      
base    varchar(16)      
econ    int(6)           
location    varchar(12)  
x   int(2)           
y   int(2)           
galaxy  int(2)           
planet  int(2)           
comment     varchar(100)     
ipaddress   varchar(45)
```

and on the page when this segment of php is called i will have 
the  econ,X,Y,Galaxy,and planet of another entry

then i want to display the entry is the database(like i do at the moment) BUT
i want a new column to be displayed that is not in the DB, this new column is to be the output of a calculation..
the calculation is to be

```
Sqrt(min. Economy) x ( 1 + Sqrt(Distance)/75 + Sqrt(Players)/10 )
Sqrt(88) x ( 1 + Sqrt(23)/75 + Sqrt(23)/10 ) = 15 cred./h
```

players is another variable that is already available in my page

Distance is a function of the 2 galaxys unless there the same when its a function of the 2 x's and y's unless there the same and then its a function of the 2 planet integers

here is the page i talk of..i will add a new button to compare.. thats the new function that i want to compare the given value with existing values.
http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/trade/postroute2.php

Comment: Same as Jeremy, I don't get what your stuck on.

Comment: the question is how to implement the reults column... sems to be answered :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just calculate in your query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT (Sqrt(min. Economy) x ( 1 + Sqrt(Distance)/75 + Sqrt(Players)/10 )    Sqrt(88) x ( 1 + Sqrt(23)/75 + Sqrt(23)/10 ) = 15 cred./h) as `Distance`, * FROM routes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8;";
```

Use as for naming your calculation so its become a column and use * to get the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

After the query you store the results into an array. You could parse the array adding an item containing the calculation that you wrote.
If you want more details you should past here the array

--
dam